# How to create a login system that stores user data for beginners?

Tags: javascript, authentication, backend

I'm working on my first web app using ReactJs and have the frontend pretty much done. Now I want to be able to pair the user's data with their username so next time they log in, everything will be exactly as they left it. The user's data is currently all in a JavaScript object so I think I want to save it as a json file. However, I have no clue how to even start this.

My first issue comes with creating the login system. Obviously I cannot just store the username and password in plain text so I would need to encrypt and decrypt it somehow. However, I am currently hosting my site on Netlify so I would need to pass that information over there somehow and the only way I can think of is by adding it to my GitHub repo which is public so anyone can then see my encryption algorithm.

I'm not even sure if this is even how you do it since I've never done anything like this before. Does anyone know where I should start? I don't need something super sophisticated just reasonable.

Comment: Have you heard of databases? Saving information as json files is terribly inefficient and unsafe. As for the authentication, your security can not possibly rely on the secrecy of the algorithm. All the proper ways to encrypt data are already public and known. You would have a secret key that you would pass into your program as an environment variable or something, to remain private. That being said there is an abundance of tutorials to build authentication systems, this question as it is, is too broad for Stackoverflow

Comment: Have a look at Google's Firebase or FireStore services. Can use it for free with a small site and offers storage and user authentication

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use google's firebase and firestore services. They have an amazing documentation on their [website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) too and there's plenty of resources online. google for firebase authentication tutorial and you'll find a whole lot.